# CMSMS File Download Problems

Tags: file, content-management-system, download

I'm using the CMS Made Simple platform; which I'm not very familiar with!

The site has a secure frontend, which contains a document library for members. Files are stored outside the document root and links are generated by the CMS so you should only be able to get the documents if you're logged in.

At first glance the setup works fine; however certain PDFs uploaded in this fashion are corrupt upon download, and line endings in text files aren't preserved.

Sorry if this is a bit vague, I'm hoping someone has come across a similar problem but any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Rich

Answer (score 0):

You should check which module/tag is handling the download / upload.

Are you sure they´re intact when uploaded?

Check for headers, and content size calculation, try different browsers and different methods to force the download.